# Importing super slow and resets

Tags: mining

I ran `geth --rpc`. I got to block ~15,000,000 but then it suddenly went back to ~4,000,000. Now it's super slow. Maybe 1 minute per block. Why is it suddenly so slow? I never got a finished message. Did I finish and new blocks are just being created?

Comment: Are you synchronizing the blockchain or importing it from another instance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. From what I remember there isnt something that will explicitly tell you you are done. You will continue to sync with the new blocks. You can check the block number against [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io)